# How to avoid R errors while writing queries with single and double quotes

Tags: r, r-dbi

I have a problem while writing Query at R to select Data from Presto Database.
I used the next code with

```
    library(DBI)
    library(dplyr)
    library(RPresto)
    res = dbSendQuery(con, " select RESPONDENT as Respondent,RESPONSE_DATE 
    as Date,
    MAX(CASE
    WHEN QUESTION_ID = '18' AND RESPONSE_ID ='5' THEN 'Very Satisfied'
    WHEN QUESTION_ID = '18' AND RESPONSE_ID ='4' THEN 'Satisfied'
    WHEN QUESTION_ID = '18' AND RESPONSE_ID ='3' THEN 'Neutral'
    WHEN QUESTION_ID = '18' AND RESPONSE_ID ='2' THEN 'Dissatisfied'
    WHEN QUESTION_ID = '18' AND RESPONSE_ID ='1' THEN 'Very Dissatisfied' 
    ELSE NULL END) AS "How was our service looks based on your last meal?"
    from surveytable
    group by 1,2")
```

Errors appeared at R like

```
    Error: unexpected numeric constant in:
    "                WHEN QUESTION_ID = '18' AND RESPONSE_ID ='2' THEN 
    'Dissatisfied' 
    WHEN QUESTION_ID = '18' AND RESPONSE_ID ='1' THEN 'Very Dissatisfied' 
    ELSE NULL END) AS "7."
    >                 from dev_bi.Checkmarket_survey_78995
    Error: unexpected symbol in "                from 
    dev_bi.Checkmarket_survey_78995"
    >                 group by 1,2
    Error: unexpected symbol in "                group by"
    >                 limit 1")
    Error: unexpected numeric constant in "                limit 1"
```

Comment: If you use a highlighting editor that is aware of R syntax then these situations will be obvious as you enter them. https://r-dir.com/blog/2013/01/list-of-r-editors.html

Comment: Thanks and Appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prepend every double quote in you query with backslash. See this:

```
query <- " select RESPONDENT as Respondent,RESPONSE_DATE 
    as Date,
    MAX(CASE
    WHEN QUESTION_ID = '18' AND RESPONSE_ID ='5' THEN 'Very Satisfied'
    WHEN QUESTION_ID = '18' AND RESPONSE_ID ='4' THEN 'Satisfied'
    WHEN QUESTION_ID = '18' AND RESPONSE_ID ='3' THEN 'Neutral'
    WHEN QUESTION_ID = '18' AND RESPONSE_ID ='2' THEN 'Dissatisfied'
    WHEN QUESTION_ID = '18' AND RESPONSE_ID ='1' THEN 'Very Dissatisfied' 
    ELSE NULL END) AS \"How was our service looks based on your last meal?\"
    from surveytable
    group by 1,2"
cat(query)
```

Comment: @Hady Could you please accept the answer if it helped you?